# tfs build email changes of last successful build

Tags: msbuild

Is there some nice way, of sending all changes since last successful build and send me the changes?

I would prefer update my workflow process rather than *.proj file.
Any example would be appreciated.

so far I have found: [Programatically find TFS changes since last good build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220813/programatically-find-tfs-changes-since-last-good-build)

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? While I do no keep up with features in each release, I can tell you that this report is generated automatically in TFS2012. Every time a build is successfully completed, I receive an email with the cumulative changes, including each changeset, and all items included. It is important that you require the developers to use the "Add work item by ID" feature when checking in code. This is a configuration that you can set for each project in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not fully functional but start is history command

http://daysincode.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/tfs-history-command.html